# Can't stop Sinatra using Ctrl+C when `require 'coffee-script'`

Tags: ruby, node.js, sinatra, coffeescript, ruby-1.9.2

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2p180 on Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit.

I have the simplest possible [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) example using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) which runs fine, but doesn't stop when I press the `Ctrl+C` shortcut. So every time I have to `kill -9` and it's getting quite tedious.

The `app.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'coffee-script'

get '/' do
  '<script src="/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'
end

get '/app.js' do
  coffee :app
end
```

The `views/app.coffee`:

```
alert 'Foo'
```

It **works** on Ruby 1.8.7 with minor modifications:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'coffee-script'
require 'json'

get '/' do
  '<script src="/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'
end

get '/app.js' do
  coffee :app
end
```

It **also works** on 1.9.2 when I remove the line `require 'coffee-script'`, but gives me a warning:

```
WARN: tilt autoloading 'coffee_script' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'coffee_script' suggested.
```

Figured out that it **works** when using `therubyracer`, but fails on `node`. The version 0.1.97 from Ubuntu 10.10 repositories is the only exception. When using the 0.2.6 from Natty, it fails and also when installing the latest (0.4.8) using nvm, I wasn't able to install 0.1.97 via nvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ruby 1.9.2, Sinatra 1.3.2, CoffeeScript 2.2.0 and Node 0.6.2 this does not occur anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to replicate. I'm on a Mac (OS 10.6.7) running bash and Ruby 1.9.2p180. I don't get your `tilt` warning, either.

I also haven't experienced this problem when using The Middleman (Sinatra-based) or Rails 3.1; both use the same `coffee-script` gem (as does Tilt; I suspect the `coffee_script` is just a typo).

Have you tried updating all the pertinent gems (sinatra, coffee-script, tilt, execjs) to their latest versions? What JS environment do you have on your system (e.g. do you have `node`, or are you relying on `therubyracer`)?

Comment: I'm running the latest 64-bit Ubuntu and also have Ruby 1.9.2p180. Just updated the gems, only execjs was outdated, but I didn't solve this. I have node on my system.

Comment: You were correct about the JS environment. I have `node`, and I tried it out with `therubyracer` and it worked. Seems to be then some interoperability issue with Ruby and Node.